# Using RbConfig instead of Config in a Rack app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

Although, it seems to be a popular issue, I didn't find anything relevant. The issue is that I keep having this kind of an error in the console while I'm using the Sinatra app

```
/home/alan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
```

I run the app as

```
bundle exec shotgun
```

What should I do get rid of it?

Comment: This is an issue in rake (as the warning denotes). gem install rake should get you a correct version, but it's not a big deal if you don't mind the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is actually wrong. It just warns about the module which was renamed. 
if you still want to get rid of it I would recommend you to upgrade rake.

```
gem update rake
```